# Missing entries in join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I've got a question about a query.

I've got two tables. The first table has to columns, a start-date and an end-date.
For example *start:* **00:00:00** and *end:* **00:15:00**

The first table **period**:

```
|---start---|----end----|
| 00:00:00  | 00:15:00  |
| 00:15:01  | 00:30:00  |
| 00:30:01  | 00:45:00  |
| 00:45:01  | 01:00:00  |
|-----------|-----------|
```

The seconds table **tt** contains following information: name,zeit,points

```
|---name---|----zeit----|---points---|
|   AAAA   |  00:11:00  |     5      |
|   AAAA   |  00:12:00  |     5      |
|   BBBB   |  00:08:00  |     9      |
|   BBBB   |  00:10:00  |     9      |
|   CCCC   |  00:13:00  |     8      |
|   AAAA   |  00:31:00  |     1      |
|   BBBB   |  00:37:00  |     3      |
|   AAAA   |  00:47:00  |     7      |
|   BBBB   |  00:50:00  |     2      |
|   CCCC   |  00:55:00  |     4      |
|----------|------------|------------|
```

I've used the following query to summarize the points of each team grouped by the period:

```
SELECT
   period.end,
   IFNULL(sum(tt.punkte), 0) punkte,
   tt.name
FROM period
   LEFT JOIN tt ON (tt.zeit < period.end AND tt.zeit >= period.start)
GROUP BY period.end,tt.name
```

With this query I get this result:

```
|---end----|---punkte---|----name----|
| 00:15:00 |     10     |    AAAA    |
| 00:15:00 |     18     |    BBBB    |
| 00:15:00 |      8     |    CCCC    |
| 00:45:00 |      1     |    AAAA    |
| 00:45:00 |      3     |    BBBB    |
| 01:00:00 |      7     |    AAAA    |
| 01:00:00 |      2     |    BBBB    |
| 01:00:00 |      4     |    CCCC    |
|----------|------------|------------|
```

As you can see the results table is missing the rows with **end** 00:30:00 and there are only two rows with **end** 00:45:00.

So I've tried everything to add these rows to the result:

```
| 00:30:00 |      0     |    AAAA    |
| 00:30:00 |      0     |    BBBB    |
| 00:30:00 |      0     |    CCCC    |
| 00:45:00 |      0     |    CCCC    |
```

How can I change the query to get these missing rows to my result?

Comment: looking on Your data - You not have this rows in source, and group work correct. from where You plan request data for 30:00? (You not provide no one and all provided - proper result)

Comment: agree, it more pretty solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, that doesn't use dynamic SQL would be to first `CROSS JOIN` the `period` with a (derived) table that holds `DISTINCT name` values from `tt` and then `LEFT JOIN tt`:

```
SELECT 
    period.end,
    n.name,
    IFNULL(SUM(tt.punkte), 0) AS punkte
FROM  
        period 
    CROSS JOIN 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tt ) AS n 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tt 
    ON 
       tt.name = n.name 
       AND (tt.zeit < period.end AND tt.zeit >= period.start) 
GROUP BY
    period.end,
    n.name ;
```

Comment: I used your solution and it works. Thank you very much for your and all other replies.

Answer (score 1):

idea next - for each distinct name we can calculate proper result:

```
SELECT
    `end` ,
    'AAAA' AS `name` ,
    IFNULL((SELECT
                SUM(points) FROM tt WHERE
                tt.`name` = 'AAAA' AND (tt.zeit < period.END AND tt.zeit >= period.START)) , 0) AS punkte
FROM
    period
```

next step UNION ALL result for each unique name
In common case (when more than 3 names) it could be:

```
SET @query_text = 

                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.query_text SEPARATOR " UNION ALL ") 
                FROM (
                SELECT

                    CONCAT("SELECT `end`, '", `name`,"' as `name`, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(points) FROM tt WHERE tt.`name` = '",`name`,"' and (tt.zeit < period.end AND tt.zeit >= period.start)),0) as punkte FROM period") as query_text

                FROM tt GROUP BY `name`) t1);

PREPARE long_query_text FROM @query_text;
EXECUTE long_query_text;
```

```
00:15:00    AAAA    10 
00:15:00    BBBB    18 
00:15:00    CCCC    8 
00:30:00    AAAA    0 
00:30:00    BBBB    0 
00:30:00    CCCC    0 
00:45:00    AAAA    1 
00:45:00    BBBB    3 
00:45:00    CCCC    0 
01:00:00    AAAA    7 
01:00:00    BBBB    2 
01:00:00    CCCC    4
```

prepare statements, than execute prepared